# Android room DB - Handling of foreignKeys in DB upgrade and Altering the table

Tags: android, sql, foreign-keys, android-room, android-room-relation

I'm using a room DB. I've 2 tables A and B.

The primary key of A is foreign key in Table B.

**Below is my DB structure -**

```
@Entity(tableName = "A")
  data class A(
  @PrimaryKey
  @NotNull
  @ColumnInfo(name = "IDKEY")
  var xID: String
)

@Entity(
tableName = "B",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = A::class,
    parentColumns = ["IDKEY"],
    childColumns = ["KEY"],
    onDelete = NO_ACTION
)])
data class B(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "KEY")
    var id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IDKEY")
    var parentIDId: String)
```

Now I want to delete the table A from the room database. However table B will be there.
So how should I handle this migration? I'm specifically looking out for removing the foreignKeys constraint. Not able to figure it out. I believe that should be removed before deleting the parent table A.

Also certain columns in Table B will be deleted.

*So here's what I'm thinking about the approach -*

1. Remove foreign key constraints (need solution on how to do this?)
2. Delete table A
3. Alter table B

Please guide me on point 1 and suggest me if any better approach to deal with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by Creating a table based upon table B e.g.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B_temp;
 CREATE TABLE B_temp AS SELECT * FROM B;
```

- see https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#create_table_as_select_statements

Then delete all rows from table B e.g.

```
DELETE FROM B;
```

Then DROP (or RENAME and DROP later) TABLE A;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
```

The make the alterations to table B.

Then reload table B with the data from the B_temp table e.g.

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM B_temp;
```

Finally drop the B_temp table;

An Alternative would be to use the `SupportSQliteDatabase`'s [`setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean)) before (false) and after (true). In which case the Foreign Keys will not be enforced and therefore you could just  perform the steps you have specified.

**Example using method 1**

The following is a working example based upon the code in your question.

**Pre-Migration - Version 1 with some data.**

The @Dao annotated **AllDao** abstract class:-

@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

```
/* Will be commented out (deleted) for Version 2 */
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
abstract fun insert(a: A): Long

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
abstract fun insert(b: B): Long
@Query("SELECT * FROM B")
abstract fun getAllFromB(): List<B>
```

}

An @Database annotated class **TheDatabase** for Version 1 and 2 :-

```
const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
@Database(entities = [A::class,/*<<<<< NOTE will be commented out for Version 2*/B::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        private val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B_temp")
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B_temp AS SELECT * FROM B;")
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM B")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B")
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B` (`KEY` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `IDKEY` TEXT NOT NULL)")
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM B_temp")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** the CREATE TABLE for the new table **B** was copied from the generated java after compiling when the changes for version 2 were made.
- Run on the main thread for convenience and brevity.

An activity **MainActivity** that will, when at version 1, load some data into both tables A and B:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        if (DATABASE_VERSION == 1) {

            /* Will be commented out for Version 2 */
            dao.insert(A("1"))
            dao.insert(A("2"))
            dao.insert(A("3"))

            dao.insert(B(id = 1,parentIDId = "ID001"))
            dao.insert(B(id = 2,parentIDId = "ID002"))
            dao.insert(B(id = 3,parentIDId = "ID003"))
        }

        /* Write the schema to the log */
        val suppdb = db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        val csr = suppdb.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO",
                "Component is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"))} " +
                        "Type is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type"))} " +
                        "SQL is \n\t${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("sql"))}")
        }
        /* Write the data in table B to the log */
        for(b in dao.getAllFromB()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","KEY = ${b.id} IDKEY = ${b.parentIDId}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** :-

```
2022-03-03 08:39:35.353 D/DBINFO: Component is android_metadata Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-03-03 08:39:35.353 D/DBINFO: Component is A Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE `A` (`IDKEY` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`IDKEY`))
2022-03-03 08:39:35.353 D/DBINFO: Component is sqlite_autoindex_A_1 Type is index SQL is 
        null
2022-03-03 08:39:35.354 D/DBINFO: Component is B Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE `B` (`KEY` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `IDKEY` TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`KEY`) REFERENCES `A`(`IDKEY`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION )
2022-03-03 08:39:35.354 D/DBINFO: Component is sqlite_sequence Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2022-03-03 08:39:35.354 D/DBINFO: Component is room_master_table Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
```

- android_metadata is a table created by the android SQLite API
- sqlite_sequence is a table created if ANY tables include the AUTOINCREMENT keyword
- room_master_table is created by Room, it stores the hash which is generated according to the schema and is used for detecting a changed schema.

**AND:-**

```
2022-03-03 08:39:35.361 D/DBINFO: KEY = 1 IDKEY = ID001
2022-03-03 08:39:35.361 D/DBINFO: KEY = 2 IDKEY = ID002
2022-03-03 08:39:35.361 D/DBINFO: KEY = 3 IDKEY = ID003
```

**Migration**

Class **B** is changed to not have the Foreign Key constraint tying it to table **A* :-

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "B"/*,
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = A::class,
        parentColumns = ["IDKEY"],
        childColumns = ["KEY"],
        onDelete = NO_ACTION
    )]*/)
data class B(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "KEY")
    var id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IDKEY")
    var parentIDId: String)
```

**AllDao** has to be changed to not reference tale A so:-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    /* Will be commented out (deleted) for Version 2 */
    /*
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(a: A): Long
   
     */

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(b: B): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM B")
    abstract fun getAllFromB(): List<B>
}
```

**TheDatabase** change to Version 2 and to exclude table **A** :-

```
const val DATABASE_VERSION = 2 /*<<<<<<<<<< changed for version 2 */
@Database(entities = [/*A::class,*//*<<<<< NOTE will be commented out for Version 2*/B::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        private val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B_temp")
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B_temp AS SELECT * FROM B;")
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM B")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;")
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B")
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B` (`KEY` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `IDKEY` TEXT NOT NULL)")
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM B_temp")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity** is changed so that **A** objects are not referenced:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        if (DATABASE_VERSION == 1) {

            /* Will be commented out for Version 2

            dao.insert(A("1"))
            dao.insert(A("2"))
            dao.insert(A("3"))

             */

            dao.insert(B(id = 1,parentIDId = "ID001"))
            dao.insert(B(id = 2,parentIDId = "ID002"))
            dao.insert(B(id = 3,parentIDId = "ID003"))
        }

        /* Write the schema to the log */
        val suppdb = db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        val csr = suppdb.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO",
                "Component is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"))} " +
                        "Type is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type"))} " +
                        "SQL is \n\t${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("sql"))}")
        }
        /* Write the data in table B to the log */
        for(b in dao.getAllFromB()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","KEY = ${b.id} IDKEY = ${b.parentIDId}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

After running with the above changes  the the log includes:-

```
2022-03-03 08:53:06.016 D/DBINFO: Component is android_metadata Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-03-03 08:53:06.016 D/DBINFO: Component is sqlite_sequence Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2022-03-03 08:53:06.016 D/DBINFO: Component is room_master_table Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2022-03-03 08:53:06.017 D/DBINFO: Component is B_temp Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE B_temp("KEY" INT,IDKEY TEXT)
2022-03-03 08:53:06.017 D/DBINFO: Component is B Type is table SQL is 
        CREATE TABLE `B` (`KEY` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `IDKEY` TEXT NOT NULL)
```

- as can be seen no table **A** and table **B** has been changed accordingly (not Foreign Key constraints)

**AND The data has been preserved:-**

```
2022-03-03 08:53:06.023 D/DBINFO: KEY = 1 IDKEY = ID001
2022-03-03 08:53:06.023 D/DBINFO: KEY = 2 IDKEY = ID002
2022-03-03 08:53:06.023 D/DBINFO: KEY = 3 IDKEY = ID003
```